# Windows phone append a border to an image

Tags: windows-phone-7, bitmapimage

I'd like to append a border (20px white) to an image, save as a new jpeg image (orginal image with a border), I don't know how do I start. Can anyone give me a direction or code example?

Thanks

Comment: Is this only when displaying the image? Or are you looking to open an image file and save a new version of the file with the border?

Comment: @MrMDavidson I am looking for load an existing image, and add a border on it, then save to a new version. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways to do it:

1. On your UI, wrap the image with a Border element with the correct settings and use `new WriteableBitmap(borderElement, null)` to create a new WriteableBitmap which you can then save using the [SaveJpeg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) extension method.
2. Your other option is to use the [WriteableBitmapEx class library](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) to graphically add the graphical elements you want.

I've used both. The advantages for (1) is that there's less hassle in the sense of adding a dependeny on another DLL. The advantage in (2) is that you don't need to mess with your UI to create the image.

Comment: I prefer the first one, easy for me :).Thanks